# Plugin isn't found in visual studio

Tags: phonegap-plugins, visual-studio-2015

Environment:

- VS2015 with cordova tools.
- Win8.1.
- Practise project is WinJS ToDo sample app from web.

Maybe this is just SUE (Stupid User Error) but when I'm adding `barcodereader` plugin (config editor ui -> using git address) all goes fine and new plugin comes to plugin folder in project tree.

Problem is that I can't seem to find way to use that new plugin at all. I can add `<script src="">` tag for plugin's .js-file and it compiles, but when I try actually do something with plugin from code, it isn't recognized at all.

My new love with VS is suffering now...

Comment: Is this a TypeScript project, or JavaScript?

Comment: TypeScript, but if I haven't understand totally wrong, I can use JS in partials under platforms?

Comment: I have same problem also with multiplatform cordova template which I selected from new project wizard.
This happens in 2 separate computers, so I think it's related to my lack of knowledge and/or poor documentation of this new Visual Studio cordova toolset. So, there is probably some trick which should be done, but that isn't documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need a definition for the plugin in order to consume it in a TypeScript project. The usual place to find definitions (commonly defined in d.ts files) is on www.definitelytyped.org. However in this case, the plugin author probably has not defined a TypeScript definition so you won't find it there.

That means you'll need to write one yourself. Think of a d.ts file like a header file in c++. It defines the interfaces and contracts in the library you're consuming. It's really not too hard to write these once you've learned how to do it. Here's one link that might be useful:

https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20Definition%20%28.d.ts%29%20Files

Hope that helps.

Comment: That helped, thanks. I did some definitions and got those working, but seems that I don't have time in this project to learn TypeScript and/or WinJS, so backing to full .js project.